# Android doesnt show up in ADB

Tags: usb-debugging

I have a `Android 4.4.2` tablet here and I am trying to use ADB with it, So I launch ADB on my PC and it opens and says 'No device found'. I have the `USB Debugging` enabled in the `Developer Settings` so why wont my PC recognise it?

UPDATE: When I first connected it to my Windows 8.1 PC it said installing device and it then said finished, So if I need drivers do I have to get different ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After researching more online here is the answer:

1. [Download the Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/)

2. Extract the zip archive and locate 'android-sdk-windows\SDK Manager.exe'

3. Launch that exe and select 'Android SDK Platform-tools' and at the bottom under extras select 'Google USB Driver' then click on install packages

4. After they have finished downloading, locate 'android-sdk-windows\extras\google\usb_driver\android_winusb.inf' and right click it then select 'Install', click OK on the next couple of windows

5. Plug your android in and turn on 'Usb debugging' from the developer options in settings (On your android)

6. Go back to your pc and open the start menu and search for 'Device Manager' (Windows 8 users can right click the start icon and click on device manager)

7. Now locate a device with the name 'MTP' under 'Other devices' (It could have a different name)

8. Right click it and select 'Update Driver Software' then 'Browse my computer for driver software' then 'Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer'

9. Click Android Device, Then 'Android ADB Interface' then click on next

10. Check to see if it works by going to 'android-sdk\platform-tools\', hold down shift and right click and then select 'Open Command WIndow Here'. CMD comes up, now type `adb devices`, If your device appears then its working, if not, then repeat steps 3-10 again

Answer (score 0):

You have to install all required drivers for your PC to actually recognize your device in debugging mode. Most manufacturers softwares install those drivers and use them on their own (to do certain functions inside the program).

Usually closing that program and all related services is enough to use the drivers together with ADB.

This works like this at least for all my Samsung devices.